# How to understand and learn `instrument` package of java?

Tags: java, instrumentation

Recently, I found there is a `java.lang.instrument` package in jdk, which is used by many frameworks to reload classes or profile.

I don't find many articles of using them, is there any resource(book, article, project) to help to understand it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think this link can help to understand a little the usage of java agents:

- [Not So Secret Java Agent (1)](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-1)
- [Not So Secret Java Agent (2)](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-2)
- [Not So Secret Java Agent (3)](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-3)
- [Not So Secret Java Agent (4)](http://blogs.captechconsulting.com/blog/david-tiller/not-so-secret-java-agents-part-4)

hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

This library is for Java Instrumentation mechanism (Registering a class as MBean server) using JMX. Refer JMX guide